# How to load animator xml file on Android programatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

According to [the Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html), we can load `AnimatorSet` class programatically from xml file located on the path like this: `res/animator/filename.xml`. So I have created a sample project and tried to see if it actually works, and it doesn't; nothing happens. It would be very nice if I can understand what is missing and/or what I have done wrong. Thanks in advance! Below is my animator xml file and Java code to load the xml:

res/animator/sample.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially"
    >
  <set>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:duration="500"
        android:valueTo="400"
        android:valueType="intType"
        />
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="y"
        android:duration="500"
        android:valueTo="300"
        android:valueType="intType"
        />
  </set>
  <objectAnimator
      android:propertyName="alpha"
      android:duration="500"
      android:valueTo="1f"
      />
</set>
```

And here is my Java codes to load the xml file above:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View view) {
    // Load and start Animaton
    AnimatorSet animSet =
        (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(view.getContext(), R.animator.sample);
    animSet.setTarget(view);
    animSet.start();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error in the example given in the documentation.

Try changing the `android:valueType="intType"` to `android:valueType="floatType"`.

It works in case of **@RaymondChenon** as he is not explicitly changing the 
`android:valueType` to `int` so system is taking the default one `float`

The problem here is you are giving `android:valueType="intType"` in your **animator** which is supposed to be `android:valueType="floatType"` for the property `android:propertyName="x"` you are animating.

At runtime system look for **setter** for the property, you want to animate.
Like in your case it will look for `setX()`, but as you are defining argument type of type `int` it causes a mismatch as there is no such method, I don't know why it doesn't lead to a crash.

Look at the properties of **View** class there is a method [setX(float)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX(float))

For further understanding, you can refer [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295410/android-property-animation)

Answer (score 32):

You set contains another Set `res/animator/sample.xml`. Simplify it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially"
    >

  <objectAnimator
      android:propertyName="alpha"
      android:duration="500"
      android:valueTo="1f"
      />
</set>
```

You inflate the AnimatorSet like this

```
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.sample);
set.setTarget(fab); // set the view you want to animate
set.start();
```

So far, I haven't found a way to inflate **objectAnimator** from xml to Java. I have to wrap it inside a **Set**

Comment: @DysaniazzZ can you be more explicit ?

Comment: to avoid casting, you can use Animator instead of AnimatorSet.